# Libraries to read the dependencies in C code

Tags: javascript, c

I am developing a web application in java script where user uploads C source code and i have to show dependency between methods and classes in tree structure. I was looking at the clang source code. However i have bit confused what to look exactly!. Is there any libraries available to find dependency? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might be able to adapt https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen